# Boost 1.54 beta1 does not compile on latest OS X

Tags: xcode, logging, boost

The Boost 1.54.0 beta1 does not compile on latest OS X + Xcode? But the previous 1.53 release does.

Actually, I'm trying the newly added Log component in 1.54.0 beta1. The log component does not list OS X on its page:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0_beta1/libs/log/doc/html/log/installation.html

And is there plan for the coming 1.54.0 Release on July 1st to support OS X?

If not, why?

Comment: You might be better off posting this on boost users: http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Boost-Users-f2553780.html

Comment: What compilation errors do you see?